# The page isn't redirecting properly - PHP and IIS redirect loop

Tags: php, redirect, iis

I have a **PHP** site that is hosted in **Windows (IIS)**.  The domain is held at Network Solutions, but the site is hosted at *GoDaddy*, so I have a DNS entry at Network Solutions that resolves both the "**www**" and "**non-www**" names to the GoDaddy server where my code is.

When I put a redirect rule in my `IIS web.config` file to redirect requests from various pages, I get what appears to be a redirect loop.
**Firefox** says:

> The page isn't redirecting properly

**IE** just says:

> The page cannot be displayed

**Chrome** says:

> This page has a redirect loop

So I went to **Fiddler**, which verified a bunch of requests, with each saying the server is reporting "`Object Moved.  This document may be found here`" (with "here" being a hyperlink to the page that should be getting redirected to), only it happens over and over and over (the loop).

Could this be due to the site being hosted elsewhere than where the domain is?  I'm stuck.

Here's my web.config file (actual URL replaced with "example"):

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to forums" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="(.*\.mysite.com)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/forums.php" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Someone suggested removing the "`http://`" from the action above, which I tried, but I still get the error.

Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I never used IIS, but in apache's `.htaccess` you could add a HTTP response status code along with the redirect. For example `301` is used when a page has been `permanently moved`.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed a stupid error:  In the  block,

```
<add input="(.*\.mysite.com)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
```

The area to search should have been specified, as well as the pattern to match against in a separate argument.  There was no "pattern=" statement! It should have been like so:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*\.mysite.com)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
```

DOH!  I'm tired.